# How do I change the y-axis into a dollar format and avoid scientific notation?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyverse

I am trying to learn how to assign a dollar format to a Y-axis and avoid scientific notation. I have `options(scipen = 999)`.

```
  ggplot(diamonds, aes(y = cut_width(price, 2000, boundary = 0), x = carat)) +
    geom_boxplot(varwidth = TRUE) +
    scale_y_continuous(dollar_format()) +
    xlab("Carat") +
    ylab("Price")
```

The above returns: `Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale`. I have tried tinkering around with the code by removing `cut_width` and simplifying the plot to no avail. What am I missing? Thank you!

Comment: These labels are produced by `cut` (called from `cut_width`), so you'd need to either pass a vector of formatted level names to `labels` or do some string processing on them after the fact

Comment: Don't mess with `scipen`  That's almost exclusively for handling numbers in the console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason this is not working is because `cut_width` returns a factor rather than a number. Therefore `scales::dollar_format` can't work, because it isn't a number. Additionally, you can't use `_scale_continuous` for a factor.

Here is an approach using `dig.lab =` and then reformatting the y axis labels with `str_replace_all` from `stringr`.

We need `dig.lab =` to prevent the scientific notation. See `help(cut_width)`.

As you know, we can ask `ggplot` to transform the y-axis labels with a function, so we will take advantage of this and define an anonymous function to make some replacements within the strings. Using `stringr::str_replace_all`, we can provide a named vector of `pattern = replacement` pairs. Thus, we replace `(` or `[` with `$`, `,` with `- $`, and `]` with nothing. We need to escape special regex characters with `\\`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(stringr)
ggplot(diamonds, aes(y = as.factor(cut_width(price, 2000, boundary = 0, dig.lab=10)), x = carat)) +
    geom_boxplot(varwidth = TRUE) +
    scale_y_discrete(labels = function(x) str_replace_all(x, regex(c("[\\(\\[]" = "$", "," = " - $", "\\]" = "")))) +
    xlab("Carat") +
    ylab("Price")
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure how well it integrates with `ggplot` but the  `formattable` package is a quick and easy way to make numeric values look like  "$34,000,32"  . Sure beats a monster `regex` :-)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I figured there was another package that has solved this issue before. It's a tough balance between answering a question with 10 new packages or just sticking to those within the realm of the ones the OP is using already.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think `scales::label_dollar` works on output of `cut_width`.

Comment: Even if you don't turn the output into a factor?

Comment: Looking at the source it expects the input to be numeric.

Comment: To go off of Ian Campbell's answer, If you prefer to leave the bounding notations, you could do the following `function(x){str_replace_all(x,"([0-9]+)","$\\1" }`

Comment: Thank you for this solution. Can you explain why the function seems to create a break in the continuity of the code? For example copying all the code and hitting Ctrl+Enter produces the desired result. But attempting to run from the last line `ylab("Price")` returns the error: `Error: unexpected ')' in:
"                                "," = " - $",
                                "\\]" = ""))))"
>   xlab("Carat") +
+   ylab("Price")
Error in xlab("Carat") + ylab("Price") : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator`

Comment: @GabrielAlain I suspect you're missing an opening `(`. Alternatively, try placing the cursor in the first line with `ggplot`. You can put all of the `scale_y_discrete` in the same line if you want, I only break it up for formatting on Stack Overflow. I edited my answer to do so, see if that helps.

Comment: @JustinLandis Your method works however the formatting is not as clean or complete as the result provided by Ian Campbell.

Comment: @IanCampbell I too thought it was a missing `(` however I couldn't seem to find out where. I'm certain it is a "me" issue. Your edited code works perfectly. Thanks again!

Comment: @IanCampbell  so   `as.numeric(stuff)`

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to grab the package `scales` .  The overview there says it's designed to create useful strings for labelling in `ggplot`.   Quoting from the help section of `label_dollar`

> Labelling functions are designed to be used with the labels argument
>   of ggplot2 scales. The examples demonstrate their use with x scales,
>   but they work similarly for all scales, including those that generate
>   legends rather than axes.